# Download and open any type of file that iOS can handle

Tags: objective-c, download, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking in my iOS project. Similar to how a native e-mail application handles attachments, I want to download files which could be of any type (docx, pdf, jpg, etc) and open them in the appropriate application.

I'm downloading the file from a .NET web service through an HTTP GET request. This service returns a .NET `FileContentResult` which is basically a byte array for the file content, a string for the content type, and a string for the file name.

I'm hoping there's some Objective-C API for opening abstract files which it knows how to handle in some native way, similar to how a browser can dynamically decide how to open a file based on the file type.

The current code I have is:

```
....
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
....

[httpClient getPath:[url path] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response: '%@'", responseStr);

    ....
}
```

The `responseStr` that I log is `(null)` for images but looks reasonable for basic text files. I'm assuming since it's `(null)` for images, it would also be failing similarly for pdf files among other things.

Can somebody help me figure out how to do this using a .NET web service, AFNetworking, and the Objective-C API? Thanks.